# How do these topological results imply the inverse function theorem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75049/69037), Terrence Tao inquires about the everywhere differentiable inverse function theorem. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/75118/69037) claims the theorem may be deduced from fairly intricate topological results of Cernavskii.

I've looked around and found the following two theorems which are claimed to generalize Cernavskii's results. I would like to understand how they're related, and how they imply the inverse function theorem.

The following is specifically introduced as a generalization of Cernavskii's results.

**Theorem 1.** [[Thm 3](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2043652?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)] Let $(M,d)$ be a closed $n$-dimensional topological manifold with metric $d$ inducing the topology. There is an $\varepsilon >0$ such that if $Y$ is a closed topological manifold and $M\overset{f}{\to} Y$ is a proper surjection with finite fibers but not a homeomorphism, then there's at least one $y\in Y$ such that $\operatorname{diam}f^{-1}(y)\geq \varepsilon$ (the diameter is defined via the metric $d$ on $M$).

The second theorem lives in the setting of branched covering maps, and requires a preliminary definition to state.

**Definition.** A subset $A\subset X$ *separates $X$ locally at $x\in X$* if there's a neighborhood $U\ni x$ such that for each neighborhood $V\ni x$ in $U$, the set $V\setminus A$ is not connected.

**Theorem 2.** Let $U\overset{f}{\to} V$ be an open map with discrete fibers between opens in $\mathbb R ^n$. Then the set on which $f$ is *not* a local homeomorphism has empty interior, and does not locally separate $U$ at any point.

---

**Question 1.** (How) Does each of the above theorems imply the inverse function theorem?

**Question 2.** What's the relation between the theorems? Does either imply the other?